# Beamer headline height or depth insufficient with compressed miniframes

Tags: beamer, height, depth

I use beamer with a headline containing compressed miniframes navigation content:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}

\begin{document}
    \section{First}
    \frame{First-first}
    \frame{First-second}
    \section{Second}
    \frame{Second-first}
    \frame{Second-second}
\end{document}
```

The height or depth of the headline seems insufficient in the sense that the colored headline space below the slide circles is insufficient to my tastes, as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image: cutout of left-hand side of headline and bottom of slide above]

There should be about the same space below the circles as above the section titles.

*How can I add such space or make another change with the same visual effect?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redefine the headline and add as much space as you want (see the `<- change here` comment in the code below):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip20pt % <- change here
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{First}
    \frame{First-first}
    \frame{First-second}
    \section{Second}
    \frame{Second-first}
    \frame{Second-second}
\end{document}
```

[image]